# Copy a range of cells from a worksheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am intending to copy a range of cells from a worksheet called "STN-1" to another workbook in sheet1,by using a "submit" button.
The code i have written is like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim MyData As Workbook

Set MyData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\askhan\dropbox\surgery\osce bank\SUR-OSCE 
AY2014-15-G1-QUESTIONS.XLSX")
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:f50").Select
Selection.Copy
Range ("a1:f50")
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
MyData.Save
End Sub
```

But it is giving compile error.  If someone can correct this code please, I am very new to using macros.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  You can avoid `Select` entirely. The `.Copy` argument allows an optional parameter to specify the destination, like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myData as Workbook

Set MyData = Workbooks.Open( _
    "C:\Users\askhan\dropbox\surgery\osce bank\SUR-OSCE AY2014-15-G1-QUESTIONS.XLSX")

MyData.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:f50").Copy _
    Workbooks("Other Book").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
MyData.Save


End Sub
```

Of course you will want to modify the destination workbook/sheet/range destination to fit your needs.

Comment: can you write full code pls Mr. David.  it s giving run time error 9, subscript out of range

Comment: that error means you specify to workbook or a worksheet that doesn't exist.

Comment: when you mean "that doesn't exist" is your direction to "Other Book" in the code or what? so do you mean, I give correct path like c:\Users...etc?

Comment: You need not give the full path, just the file *name* and that file must be open at the time.  There are three potential points for that error, in tihs code: I *think* you need to change this part: `MyData.Worksheets("sheet1")` to this instead: `MyData.Worksheets("STN-1")`. And yes, `"Other Book"` should be changed to the name of the workbook where you want the data copied *to*.  Note: your question is not very clear about which sheet is in which book, nor which is the source nor which is the destination of the copy. Consider revising your Q to more fully describe the problem?